# No change event triggered in p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm struggling with the following issue in a web application using PrimeFaces 6.2 - and yes, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501810/custom-selectitems) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945968/selectitems-values) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905878/understanding-selectitemgroup#) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462359/primefaces-selectitem-onclick-event) and the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info) and took a look into the [primefaces showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml)  as well.

**The scenario:**
I have a selectOneMenu that gets its selectItems from a bean:

```html
<p:selectOneMenu id="konfiguration" value="#{tpsManager.selectedKonfig}" > 
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{tpsManager.konfigChange}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{tpsManager.konfigurationen}" /> 
</p:selectOneMenu>​
```

If the values are computed like this by getKonfigurationen() in the bean, a change-event is triggered if the user selects an item and konfigChange() is called:

```
ArrayList konfigurationen = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
SelectItemGroup g1 = new SelectItemGroup("<Auswertungsbasis>");
g1.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{ new SelectItem("id Denver", "Denver" ),  new SelectItem("id San Francisco", "San Francisco" )  });
konfigurationen.add(g1);
konfigurationen.add(0, new SelectItem("id new York", "New York" ));
return konfigurationen;
```

This is nice, but unfortunately I need to create the selectItems in the selectItemGroup dynamically since those values are provided by a database. In the following snippet the third line returns an Array of selectItem and adds this to SelectItemGroup g1. The array contains selectItem-objects (containing Strings) only and NO null entries.

```
ArrayList konfigurationen = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
SelectItemGroup g1 = new SelectItemGroup("<Auswertungsbasis>");
g1.setSelectItems( al.toArray(new SelectItem[al.size()]) );
konfigurationen.add(g1);
konfigurationen.add(0, new SelectItem("id new York", "New York" ));
return konfigurationen;
```

**The problem:**
if the user now selects an item **NO** change-event is triggered and konfigChange() is **NOT** called. No exception is raised. In the debugger both arrays look identially. I'm out of ideas - any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi, it is good practice in Stackoverflow to create a [mcve]. I think the problem you run into is related to #4 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value. But I can only be sure when you have shown an [mcve]. Please do include scope annotations in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is good practice in Stackoverflow to create a [mcve]. I think the problem you run into is related to #4 in [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value). But I can only be sure when you have shown an [mcve]. Please do include scope annotations in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your hint lead me to the solution: the value of the iterating component has been altered and that was the problem. For the future I will try to use mcves :)